# disable spam filter contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, spam-prevention

I have a contact form on a website I'm working on. We're using Contact Form 7 and I've run into a snag. They use the form to register campers and a single user might fill out a form 3 or 4 times with several pieces of information being identical to what was already uploaded.

The Spam filter frequently tags forms as Spam and my client wants me to disable the spam filter on this altogether.

How do I do this? I have deleted akismet, I'm using Re-Captcha as a system to verify people and it still blocks forms as spam.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue while developing.
To solve it I added the code below to the functions.php file in the theme directory:

```
    add_filter('wpcf7_spam', function() { return false; });
```

wpcf7_spam - Form 7 hook which allows you to change spam check result.
Probably it's not a good idea to leave this code on production:)

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress default *CONFIG -> DISCUSSION* is applying the disallowed words list to the CF7 forms.

To fix this try adding this code snippet to your theme functions.php file:

```
/**
 * CONTACT FORM 7
 * Disable WP Disallowed List for SPAM validation
 */
add_filter( 'wpcf7_submission_has_disallowed_words', '__return_false', 10, 2 );
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

There is no filter on Contact Form 7. May be, you are using external plugin for spam control like `Honeypot` or your hosting/server making it spam. Possibility is, your hosting/server marks the email as spam. So disable any spam filter of your hosting or contact with your hosting admin.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify it's contact form 7 itself that marks the entry as spam. I have no apps or add-ons with any kind of spam protection. A user cannot submit a form too quickly after they already have with information too similar. Contact form 7 flags it as spam after the submit button is pressed and it won't go through.

Comment: How can we disable the spam protection? did you find the solution? @OSTBear

Comment: There is antispam filter in Contact Form 7. There is even an error message to be displayed to users if their submission gets detected as spam.